# how can I do to use slideToggle between display:none and display:inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use slideToggle() function to apply "less and more" behavior to a paragraph which contain a ".more" class:

html code:

```
<p class="more">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut...
    <span class="HiddenText" style="display: none;">
        aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim 
        id est laborum.
    </span>
    <a class="readmore" href="" style="display: block;">show more</a>
</p>
```

here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
        
    $('.readmore').click(function(){

        var text = $(this).text() == 'show more' ? 'show less' : 'show less';
        $(this).text(text);

        $(this).prev().slidetoggle(); 
        // here the problem 
        // $(this).prev() eq $('.hiddenText')
        // slideToglle transforme "display:none" property to "display:inline-block" 

        return false;
    });
});
```

I apply the slideToggle function to span.hiddenText element, but this function transform "display: none" to "display: inline-block", I want to toggle between "display: none" and  "display: inline".

onclick behavior : using slideToggle() function:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

onclick behavior : using toggle() function:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi utaliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

problem: slideToggle function create a return line in the paragraph.

normally, since I used a span which the display property is an inline, slideToggle must use a display:inline instead of display:inline-block.

Note: when I use toggle() in place of slideToggle() it work perfectly (display:none to display:inline)

how can I do to use slideToggle between display:none and display:inline?

Comment: Could you include the HTML as well? A jsfiddle would also be nice.

Comment: HTML is paragraph with class="more"

Comment: I literally do not see any HTML markup in your post, other than a few lines in the JS code block. Please provide an HTML markup block, and, if you can, a jsfiddle with your code so others can easily work with it.

Comment: Can you just bind the click event to .css({"display" : "none"}) and .css({"display" : "inline"}) by starting with display:none and then toggling the .css?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

**HTML:**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, has at tractatos voluptaria. Pri ne ipsum primis apeirian, mel an menandri instructior. <span class="hide"> Cum quando nominati iracundia te. His tollit eripuit lucilius at, mei quis volutpat deseruisse ex, dicunt habemus iudicabit et qui. Ad voluptua insolens mel, ei enim esse tamquam nam.</span><a id="clickme" href="#">Read more...</a>
</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        $(".hide").slideToggle("slow", function () {
            $('span.hide').toggleClass('show');
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.show {
    display: inline;
}
```

The read more link is just a generic placeholder link that goes nowhere, but clicking it fires the jQuery, which `slideToggles` the text, which then fires a function to replace the class with the show class, thus the display should be set to `inline` instead of `inline-block`.

I have a working fiddle, but the site won't let me save it to share at the moment.

Comment: If you still want it to actually toggle between using `display: none` and `display: inline` I'm pretty sure I could work that up as well, but I can't see there being that much of a difference.

Comment: toggle work fine but slideToggle create a return line, i want use slideToggle because i want to add a sliding motion.

Comment: Do you mean it adds a line return?

Comment: yes because hiddenText become a inline-block, u can see edited post

Comment: How are you determining that it has a line return added when you use `slideToggle` instead of `toggle`?

Comment: when i select span.hiddenText element by chrome or firebug i see style="display:inline-block;" attribute

Comment: Look at my changes to the jQuery and CSS items and let me know if that fixes it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function for changing the style.

```
$('.readmore').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().slideToggle("fast", function()
    {
        if(this.style.display !== "none")
            this.style.display = "inline";
    });
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: i want use slideToggle to add a sliding motion.